# How external functions call works in Solidity? Synced or Asynced?

Tags: solidity, synchronization, security

```
function redeem(uint256 _token) public {
    // transfering the token from tokenholder to owner
    token tokenBalance = token(tokenAddress);
    tokenBalance.transferToOwner(owner, _token);

    // the tokenholder gets the ethereum
    uint256 weiVal = (_mtcTokens * redeemRate);
    msg.sender.transfer(weiVal);
}
```

The **first part** of the function is transfering the token from the holder to owner by calling an external function in another contract. The **second part** is transfering the ethereum for each token transfered.

Does the first part will work in a synced manner (i.e. the code will run line by line) OR the execution of second part can happen even if the execution of first part is not completed?

Are there any security flaws (like re-entry attack etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all happens in a single thread in the EVM.

There is a reentrancy attack, which basically means a "recursive" call, when the same function is called while the previous execution of this function is not finished yet. You can read more here https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/#reentrancy

Comment: So there is no reentry attack in the code above because it's happening in single thread, right? Any example code which are prone to re-entry attack? Thanks.

Comment: Yes your code looks fine because `transfer` is called last. You can read about reentrancy here https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/#reentrancy

Comment: How to figure out if its on single thread or not?

Comment: One way is to look into evm sources https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/interpreter.go. All opcodes including CALL are executed synchronously in a single thread `res, err := operation.execute(&pc, in.evm, contract, mem, stack)`

Comment: Is it possible to check the threads on remix code editor? Thanks.

Comment: I think there is no such feature. But you can see transaction trace